# I have an array of users in my redux store the map method results in "Undefine"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to react, I have an array of users in my redux store, these users came from my backend using the axios fetch api, I noticed that I couldn't map through the empty array which I declared because the user where all nested in another array so my resulting map method was undefined.

MY REDUCER

```
import {
    GET_STATE,
     GET_USERS,
      ADD_USER,
      DELETE_USER,
        ADD_COUNT,
         SET_LOADING,
          SET_ERROR, } from './actionTypes'

const initState = {
    users: [],
    loading: false,
    error: ''
}

const userReducer = (state = initState, action)=> {
    switch(action.type) {
        case GET_STATE:
            return {
                ...state,
                ...state.users
            }
        case ADD_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                users: [action.payload, ...state.users,]
            }
        case DELETE_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                users: state.users.filter( user => user.id !== action.payload)
            }
        case ADD_COUNT:
            return {
                ...state,
                count: state.count + 1
            }
        case SET_LOADING: 
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            } 
        case SET_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: action.payload
            } 
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default userReducer
```

USER LIST COMPONENT

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { getUsers, deleteUser } from '../redux/actions'


function UsersList({users, id, getUsers, deleteUser}) {

    const myStyle = {
        display: 'block',
        padding: '10px 0',
        margintop: '5px',
        borderBottom: 'solid 2px grey'
    }
    const btnstyle = {
        cursor: 'pointer',
    }
    const tableData = {
        height: '50px',
        padding: '5px',
        margin: '2px 0',
        background: '#2c2b2c',
        padding: '2px 5px',
        'boxSizing': 'borderBox',
        textTransform: 'uppercase'
    }
    const center = {
        marginLeft: '20px'
    }



    useEffect(()=> {
        getUsers()
        console.log('======useEffect is being Called! to fetch List of Users...=========')
    }, [])

    const handleDelete = (id)=> {
        deleteUser(id)
    }

   

 const userTable = users.map( user => {

         // the close Fix i could get was to use "user.[0].lastName" i could access a property
         // but it wasnt the best idea
        console.log('From UserList component===.', user.lastName)
        console.log('From UserList component===.', user)
        return (
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>first name</td>
                    <td>last name</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div style={tableData}>
                            <button onClick={()=> handleDelete(user._id)}>{user._id}-Del</button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div style={tableData}>{user.name} </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div style={tableData}> {user.lastName} </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        )
    })



    return (
        <div className="side-bar">
        <div className="side-bar-heading">User Lists</div>
        {
            users.length ? userTable : <h3 style={center}>There are no user registered!</h3>
        }
        </div>
    )
}


const mapStateToProps = (state)=> {
    return {
        users: state.users,
        loading: state.loading
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch)=> {
    return {
        getUsers: ()=> dispatch(getUsers()),
        deleteUser: (id)=> dispatch(deleteUser(id))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UsersList)
```

Comment: can you share an example of your api response >

Comment: I think it should just be case GET_STATE:
            return {
                ...state
            }

And with your issue , you have not written any reducer called GET_USER .. it should be like

case GET_USERS:
            return {
                ...state.users
            }

And while adding user can you please console log what is inside "action.payload".

Try this meanwhile:

        case ADD_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                users: [...action.payload, ...state.users,]
            }

Comment: Thanks i found the issuse that left me stuck and not able to map through the array and i have fixed it. because i had an array embeded inside my array of users this happened because the ADD_USER action type wasnt overwriting the users array instead i was spreading the user array to insert another array